# JPA: Persist both integer and string values for an enum in oracle database using EnumConverter

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, enums

I have an enum, say MyEnum

```
Enum MyEnum {
ONE,
TWO;
}
```

and I have a JPA entity, say MyEntity

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
int id;
String name;
MyEnum someValue;
MyEnum someValueFreezed;
```

For one of the `MyEnum` value in the MyEntity table, I want to store it as a integer (0, 1, ..) and for second column, I want to store the value in DB as string (one, two, etc.). Table should look like

| ID | Name | Some_Value | Some_Value_Freezed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 | One |
| 2 | efg | 2 | Two |

I have `AttributeConvertes` in place. But with that I am able to persist only either integer or string, but not both.

Although it may seem to be a bad idea, but due to some business requirement, I has to be this way.

What is the way to persist same enum both as integer and as a string, at same time, in same table, in two different columns?

Comment: Does putting the annotation `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` at one field(or the getter, wherever your JPA annotations go to in your configuration) and `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` on the other work?

Comment: Prima facie, it is working as per my expectations. In one column, it is being stored as a string while in other it is being stored as a integer. I will try to test it with more scenarios though.. Can you please turn your comment into answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When mapping Enums to a database column JPA has 2 default mapping modes that you choose with an annotation:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

Will save the enum by saving the name ("ONE" and "TWO" in your case) of the enum constant as a String in the database column.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
```

Will use an Integer value representing the ordinal value of the Enum constant to save to the database column.

When using EnumType.STRING make sure you don't later change the names of Enum constants as that would break the mapping and when using EnumType.ORDINAL take care not to later change the order you declared the Enums as that would change their ordinal value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single setter to set two fields.

```
private String id;
private String name;

@Transient
public void setMyEnum(MyEnum e) {
    this.id = e.getId();
    this.name = e.getName();
}
```

Comment: id and name are not enum fields but are fields from a JPA entity, in which there are two MyEnum fields as well. Thanks for your response though. Can you upvote my question?